# Don't upload *.jar files to artifactory except one using org.jfrog.buildinfo

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, artifactory, jfrog-xray

I'm using this pluggin org.jfrog.buildinfo to upload files to artifactory.

It's working when I use *.jar so the jar files won't upload to artifactory. 
But when I use a regexp %regex[*.jar] It's not working.

I want to exclude all .jar files except using this regular expression:
%regex[(?!TrainBatch).*.jar]

My configuration is:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
 <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>{{VERSION}}</version>
 <inherited>false</inherited>
 <executions>
    <execution>
     <id>build-info</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>publish</goal>
        </goals>
     <configuration>
       <publisher>
         <contextUrl>{{ARTIFACTORY_URL}}</contextUrl>
         <username>{{ARTIFACTORY_USER}}</username>
         <password>{{ARTIFACTORY_PASS}}</password>
         <excludePatterns>%regex[(?!TrainBatch).*.jar]</excludePatterns>
         <repoKey>{{ARTIFACTORY_KEY}}</repoKey>
         <snapshotRepoKey>{{ARTIFACTORY_KEY_S}}</snapshotRepoKey>
       </publisher>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any ideas how to use regexp with this pluggin?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Comment: Why build something and not upload it?

Comment: `Regex matches are done over *.class files and not *.java files`

Answer (score 0):

The plugin does not support regular expressions.
It support Ant style path patterns:

- ? matches one character
- * matches zero or more characters
- ** matches zero or more 'directories' in a path